# Javascript loop when setinterval is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me to loop this script when done the interval, when the `class="cur"` goes to last `p span` i would like to loop it again. I'm practicing a javascript code and this is what i made.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="font-size: 50px">This is a test</p>
<script>
function blink() {
   $('.cur').next().css('color', '#333').addClass('cur');
   $('.cur:first').css('color', '#ccc').removeClass('cur');
}
var str = $('p').text();
var count = str.length - 1;
var splt = str.split("");
var newstr = "";
for(i=0;i<=count;i++) {
   newstr += splt[i].replace(splt[i],"<span style='color: #CCC;'>"+splt[i]+"</span>");
}
$('p').empty().append(newstr);
$('p span:first').addClass('cur').css('color','#333');
setInterval('blink()', 100);
</script>
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem with your code right now?

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout instead of setInterval?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the next `.cur` still exists.. when it doesn't exist (length 0 of the collection) start over:

```
function blink() {
   if ($('.cur').next().length == 0) {
       $('p span:first').addClass('cur').css('color','#333');
       $('p span:last').removeClass('cur').css('color','#ccc');
       return;
   }
   $('.cur').next().css('color', '#333').addClass('cur');
   $('.cur:first').css('color', '#ccc').removeClass('cur');
}
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/QKYHt/

Comment: @blink I didn't test Alnitak answer but if that other code is working then it's better as it's more optimized - I pulled quick code without putting time to optimize it. Anyway please Accept the answer you eventually will use the code from, by clicking the "V" icon to the left..

Answer (score 0):

If `$('.cur').next()` is an empty array you need to go back to the first span again:

```
function blink() {
    var cur = $('.cur');
    var next = $(cur).next();
    if (next.length == 0) {
        next = $('p span:first');
    }

   $(next).addClass('cur');
   $(cur).removeClass('cur');
}
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/cqkPV/3/

Note that this doesn't need any pre-setup - the first time it's called it'll correctly highlight the first element.  Calling `$(...).method()` on an empty list is a NoOp in jQuery.

NB: I've removed the explicit colour from the spans and the `.css` calls and moved the highlight colors into a CSS file.